# Incorrect decimal value: for column mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, insert-update

Soo I have a application that can insert and update data into my MySQL database. Inserting the data works like a charm but when I try to update the data I receive the following exception:

> ```
> Incorrect decimal value: '1,5' for column 'NumberOfHour' at row 1
> ```

This is the code im using for the update:

```
public void updateRecord(int activityID, string description, int projectID, int customerID, int hourID, int employeeID, int departmentID, int superviserID, string fixedFlex, string employeeType, decimal NumberOfHour, DateTime date, int CallID)
{

        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("database=hourregistration;server=193.78.140.90;username=Hour");

        conn.Open();
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("UPDATE activity SET Description='{0}',ProjectID='{1}',CustomerID='{2}',HourID='{3}',EmployeeID='{4}',DepartmentID='{5}',SuperviserID='{6}',FixedFlex='{7}',EmployeeType='{8}',NumberOfHour='{9}',Date='{10}',CallID='{11}' WHERE ActivityID='{12}';", description, projectID, customerID, hourID, employeeID, departmentID, superviserID, fixedFlex, employeeType, NumberOfHour, date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), CallID, activityID),conn))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
}
```

When I update the data without a decimal value (example: 5) its fine but when I try to user a comma (example: 5,1) I receive the exception..

Here is the Create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `activity` (
  `ActivityID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Description` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ProjectID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `CustomerID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `HourID` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '4',
  `EmployeeID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `DepartmentID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `SuperviserID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `FixedFlex` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmployeeType` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NumberOfHour` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `External` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `CallID` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ActivityID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=54325 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AVG_ROW_LENGTH=20 ROW_FORMAT=FIXED;
```

Comment: could you show us your create-table statement for the activity table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is in the format. You are trying to add "1,5" - try with "1.5". Can you try with point instead of a comma.

Comment: When I change the "1,5" to "1.5" the final value is "15.00"

Comment: how do you change it to result in 15.00?

Comment: Well when I insert 1.5 into the database and then have a look an the row in the database the value is 15.00

Comment: Can you try the SQL Query if you pass "1.5" as a string value? It should add it correctly to the SQL.

Comment: For some reason this worked. A string value works but a decimal value does not. Well than i just use a string ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can replace comma to dot. (I think problem is in the format either)

```
string a = sum.Text;
```

a = a.Replace(",", ".");

sum.Text = a;

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by my self. It happened when I changed the data type on MySQL and then changed it in DataSet. The solution that I found is deleting the column in the dataset, then adding the same column again, but by using the "configure" menu intem in the TableAdapter.

I hope this would be useful for you

Answer (score 0):

I used this FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION

$value_in_usd=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'value_in_usd',FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT,FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);

this $value_in_usd variable used in INSERT